# im trying to make millis in arduino work dont know how

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Hi im trying to make a restart funktion in my arduino code with millis but i can make it work.

this is how i want it to be it shutsdown the switch3 after 3 sec it restarts it.

```
  if (readString.indexOf("?b24vb2ZmL2Z1bmN0aW9u") >= 0)
  {
    //What it does.
    actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'C', false);
    switchstatus3 = false;
    delay(3000);
    actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'C', true);
    switchstatus3 = true;
  }
```

this is how how im doing it and failing.

```
  if (readString.indexOf("?b24vb2ZmL2Z1bmN0aW9u") >= 0)
  {
    //What it does.
    actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'C', false);
    switchstatus3 = false;
    timing = true;
    startTime = millis();
    if ((timing) && millis() - startTime >= 3000) {
      actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'C', true);
      switchstatus3 = true;
    }
  }
```

This is all of the arduino code.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <String.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <RemoteReceiver.h>
#include <RemoteTransmitter.h>

byte mac[] = {
  0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x00, 0x9B, 0x36
}; // MAC address
byte ip[] = {
  192, 168, 0, 200
}; // IP address
EthernetServer server(9090); // Port

//pins
ActionTransmitter actionTransmitter(9);
#define RELAY1  5
#define RELAY2  6
#define RELAY3  7
#define RELAY4  8

// Boolean funtion for state
String readString = String(30);
boolean switchstatus1 = false;
boolean switchstatus2 = false;
boolean switchstatus3 = false;
boolean Relaystatus1 = false;
boolean Relaystatus2 = false;
boolean Relaystatus3 = false;
boolean Relaystatus4 = false;

//timmer
boolean timing = false;
unsigned long startTime;

void setup() {


  //Relay default off
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);

  // Inicia o Ethernet
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);


  //enable serial data print
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // RF reciver and transmitter pins
  RemoteReceiver::init(0, 3, showCode);
  // Relay board pins
  pinMode(RELAY1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RELAY2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RELAY3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RELAY4, OUTPUT);


}

void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();

  if (client) {
    while (client.connected())
    {
      if (client.available())
      {
        char c = client.read();
        //read char by char HTTP request
        if (readString.length() < 30)
        {
          //store characters to string
          readString += (c);
        }

        //if HTTP request has ended
        if (c == '\n')
        {
          // Switch triggers by web

          // Remote switch control by web
          //switch 1 on
          if (readString.indexOf("?dW5pdDFPTg==") >= 0)
          {
            // What it does.
            actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'A', true);
            switchstatus1 = true;
          }
          //switch 1 off
          if (readString.indexOf("?dW5pdDFPRkY=") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'A', false);
            switchstatus1 = false;
          }
          //switch 2 on
          if (readString.indexOf("?dW5pdDJPTg==") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'B', true);
            switchstatus2 = true;
          }
          //switch 2 off
          if (readString.indexOf("?dW5pdDJPRkY=") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'B', false);
            switchstatus2 = false;
          }
          if (readString.indexOf("?dW5pdDNPTg==") >= 0)
          {
            //switch 3 on
            actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'C', true);
            switchstatus3 = true;
          }
          //switch 3 off
          if (readString.indexOf("?dW5pdDNPRkY=") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'C', false);
            switchstatus3 = false;
          }

          //switch 3 off deley on function.
          if (readString.indexOf("?b24vb2ZmL2Z1bmN0aW9u") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'C', false);
            switchstatus3 = false;
            timing = true;
            startTime = millis();
            if ((timing) && millis() - startTime >= 3000) {
              actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'C', true);
              switchstatus3 = true;
            }
          }

          // Relay board control by web.
          // Relay 1 on
          if (readString.indexOf("cmVsYXkxb24=") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            Relaystatus1 = true;
            digitalWrite(RELAY1, LOW);

          }
          // Relay 1 off
          if (readString.indexOf("cmVsYXkxb2Zm") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            Relaystatus1 = false;
            digitalWrite(RELAY1, HIGH);
          }
          // Relay 2 on
          if (readString.indexOf("cmVsYXkyb24=") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            Relaystatus2 = true;
            digitalWrite(RELAY2, LOW);

          }
          // Relay 2 off
          if (readString.indexOf("cmVsYXkyb2Zm") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            Relaystatus2 = false;
            digitalWrite(RELAY2, HIGH);
          }
          // Relay 3 on
          if (readString.indexOf("cmVsYXkzb24=") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            Relaystatus3 = true;
            digitalWrite(RELAY3, LOW);
          }
          // Relay 3 off
          if (readString.indexOf("cmVsYXkzb2Zm") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            Relaystatus3 = false;
            digitalWrite(RELAY3, HIGH);
          }
          // Relay 4 on
          if (readString.indexOf("cmVsYXk0b24=") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            Relaystatus4 = true;
            digitalWrite(RELAY4, LOW);
          }
          // Relay 4 off
          if (readString.indexOf("cmVsYXk0b2Zm") >= 0)
          {
            //What it does.
            Relaystatus4 = false;
            digitalWrite(RELAY4, HIGH);


          }
          // Needed to Display Site:
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println();
          client.print("<meta http-equiv='refresh'content='5'>");
          client.print("<font size='20'>");

          // Enabling command line
          client.print("ArduinoOn");
          // Remote switch state indication.
          //Switch state 1
          if (switchstatus1 == true) {
            client.print("Switch1On");
          }
          if (switchstatus1 == false) {
            client.print("Switch1Off");
          }
          //Switch state 2
          if (switchstatus2 == true) {
            client.print("Switch2On");
          }
          if (switchstatus2 == false) {
            client.print("Switch2Off");
          }
          //Switch state 3
          if (switchstatus3 == true) {
            client.print("Switch3On");
          }
          if (switchstatus3 == false) {
            client.print("Switch3Off");
          }

          // Relay state indication.
          // Relay 1
          if (Relaystatus1 == true) {
            client.print("Relay1On");
          }
          if (Relaystatus1 == false) {
            client.print("Relay1Off");
          }
          // Relay 2
          if (Relaystatus2 == true) {
            client.print("Relay2On");
          }
          if (Relaystatus2 == false) {
            client.print("Relay2Off");
          }
          // Relay 3
          if (Relaystatus3 == true) {
            client.print("Relay3On");
          }
          if (Relaystatus3 == false) {
            client.print("Relay3Off");
          }
          // Relay 4
          if (Relaystatus4 == true) {
            client.print("Relay4On");
          }
          if (Relaystatus4 == false) {
            client.print("Relay4Off");
          }
          //clearing string for next read.
          readString = "";

          // close the connection:
          client.stop();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

//RC Remote control

void showCode(unsigned long receivedCode, unsigned int period) {
  // Note: interrupts are disabled. You can re-enable them if needed.

  // Print the received code.
  Serial.print("Code: ");
  Serial.print(receivedCode);
  Serial.print(", period duration: ");
  Serial.print(period);
  Serial.println("us.");

  // Switch 1 off
  if (receivedCode == 352833)
  {
    switchstatus1 = true;

  }
  // Switch 1 Off
  if (receivedCode == 352829)

  {
    switchstatus1 = false;

  }
  // Switch 2 on
  if (receivedCode == 353805)
  {
    switchstatus2 = true;

  }
  // Switch 2 off
  if (receivedCode == 353801)

  {
    switchstatus2 = false;

  }
  // Switch 3 on
  if (receivedCode == 354129)
  {
    switchstatus3 = true;

  }
  // Switch 3 off
  if (receivedCode == 354125)

  {
    switchstatus3 = false;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what is the problem about using the first method. IF you want 3s, then simply delay 3000 and voilá. But since you want the second form, your code should look like this:

```
if (readString.indexOf("?b24vb2ZmL2Z1bmN0aW9u") >= 0)
  {
    //What it does.
    actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'C', false);
    switchstatus3 = false;
    timing = true;
    startTime = millis();
    if(timing){

        while(millis() - startTime < 3000); // This will wait 3s

        actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1, 'C', true);
        switchstatus3 = true;
    }
  }
```